# c2065:Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, identifier

I am trying to create the program described [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/14-a-first-look-at-functions/) (task 5 from the quiz), but when trying to compile I receive c2065:Undeclared Identifier. The task is to "Write a complete program that reads an integer from the user (using cin, discussed in section 1.3), doubles it using the doubleNumber() function you wrote for question 4, and then prints the doubled value out to the console". This is what I wrote, please tell me where I am wrong, I really need to know that.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>

int doubleNumber(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Your multiplied x2 number is: "<<doubleNumber(x);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: LOL, when I started to think really I found out that I've missed to write in what namespace the compiler should look. Adding using namespace std; fixed it. Sorry, as I already said i'm a total noob, so have a nice day :)

Comment: `std::cout`, `std::cin`

Answer (score 2):

cout and cin are object in std namespace. So there are two solution use namespace:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Or explicitly write it:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Your multiplied x2 number is: "<<doubleNumber(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast response, and thank you for the help. I should me more careful and it seems that I have to concentrate more. That's my 3rd program. Total noob, but we all were noobs at some time. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

OR

```
std::cout and std::cin.
```

Although latter is preferred over former.